# How do I layout an app that shifts between different "modes" programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I'd like to make an app with different views for different "modes" with some shared code (there's some elements I want always the same, and the background will be changing between different views). I'm going to manage the shifts between those views based off of time. What's the best way to layout the views?

I looked at doing a tab view, but it seems a bit unnatural since the tabbar doesn't easily hide. I can also do a custom container (my original thought), but it seems like it would be good to stay within the "standard" iOS views if possible.

Does doing a custom view seem sound / is there a better way that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also consider using UINavigationController if your modes are stack based. The navigation bar can be hidden easily (set `hidesNavigationBar` to YES). When you push or pop controllers corresponding to modes you might want to set `animated` to NO, unless the slide in/slide out animation suits you.

Answer (score 1):

I would have 2 versions of `-layoutSubviews` of the parent view. Something like:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    if ( self.mode == 0 )
    {
        [ self layoutMode0 ] ;
    }
    else if ( self.mode == 1 )
    {
        [ self layoutMode1 ] ;
    }
}
```

Your layout code can also show/hide certain views or set background images etc. In your code to switch modes, call `-setNeedsLayout`... something like this:

```
-(void)setMode:(enum Modes)newMode
{
    _mode = newMode ;
    [ self setNeedsLayout ] ;
}
```

If you want the mode switch to animate, you can do something more like this:

```
-(void)setMode:(enum Mode)newMode animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    _mode = newMode ;
    if ( animated )
    {
        [ UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            [ self layoutSubviews ] ;
        } ]
    }
    else
    {
        [ self setNeedsLayout ] ;
    }
}
```

with your ordinary setter `-setMode:` looking like this:

```
-(void)setMode:(enum Mode)newMode
{
    [ self setMode:newMode animated:NO ] ;
}
```

Comment: Checking if I understand this: I was originally hoping to keep each of the separate views with their own view controllers. If I did it this way, I wouldn't really be able to, right?

Comment: I assumed your modes are reconfigurations/varying layouts of the same set of views under one view controller. If it makes more sense to use separate view controllers, you could create your own parent view controller class to manage a set of child view controllers. Your parent view controller is responsible for loading/unloading the child view controllers' views into it's content view. You can transition nicely using `-[ UIViewController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion: ]`

Comment: Creating your own basic view controller is not too much work, and there's not really and hidden magic to it.

Comment: so, there's really not one right answer--you must decide based on your app structure..